# I am looking for a list of all the public repositories for as many different cryptocurrencies as possible

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, alternatives

I am interested in reviewing github repositories of many different cryptocurrencies to enhance my understanding and know the differences between them. Does anyone know of an online list of the links to all of the different repos?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.coingecko.com compiles the developer activities of almost all or most public traded cryptocurrencies.

They have the repo data stored on their site. Site may be hard to navigate, click Coin then choose Developer tab and look for Code Repository link. Enjoy.